# Audio intermittently starts crackling and stuttering via bluetooth headsets

Tags: firefox, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I Noticed this issue while using almost all Bluetooth headsets I used with Windows 10. Specifically when watching online videos on Mozilla Firefox.

Normally the sound would be working fine and the quality is perfect. But When I change the time of play multiple times on, for instance, a Youtube video, the sounds starts stuttering badly. It's like someone is pausing and playing the video every second but with a loud crackling noise on every pause. This same crackling is heard when I change the time of play but just for once (like a tap). It then starts kicking continuously.

Although the issue starts on Firefox only, when it happens it affects all my PC's audio. The solution is either to turn the headset off and on again or to right click on the audio icon in the task bar and switch the "Spatial Sound" mode (there are two options, "Off" and "Windows Sonic for Headphones"). No idea why it is fixing it. But once I switch it the issue goes away until the scenario is replicated.

The issue didn't happen with other browsers. Although it happened with some other applications like WhatsApp Desktop.

I tried reinstalling the driver. I also tried the solutions available online like disabling accelaration on Firefox. It didn't fix the issue.